# How to write a code to separate two qubits?

Tags: qiskit, quantum-gate, quantum-state

Is it possible to write a code to separate $\left|01\right> $ as $\left|0\right> ,\left|1\right> $ or are there any circuits i can use to get output like that?

Comment: $\left|01\right> $ is a register of 2 qubits. There is no circuit to separate them. You have to redefine your registers. One register for $\left|0\right>$ and another for $\left|1\right> $ .

Comment: How can I assign a register to two qubits?

Comment: `qiskit.QuantumCircuit(2)` defines a register of 2 qubits.

Comment: you can use qiskit.visualization.plot_bloch_multivector to visualize it

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it should be useful tu use [qutip](https://qutip.org/) to better understand what you desire (if you are familiar with python) by visualizing exactly  the 2 qubits and its state vectors (which I believe is what you seek to visualize).

I recently made a post on my personal blog that can help with that start; if you are interested, you can check it [here](https://resteche.github.io/REsteche_blog/plot_schmidt/plot_qubism/complex_array_to_rgb/entanglement/2022/04/24/qubism.html) for more details

Hope it is useful somehow!

Answer (score 0):

I found a similar answer, might be something you are looking for
https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/15514/20884

```
counts = job.result().get_counts(qc)
# New dictionary to store out results in.
new_counts = {'0': 0,
              '1': 0}

# The qubit we want the probability for
show_qubit = 1

for count in counts:
    count_idx = (len(count) - 1) - show_qubit
    new_counts[count[count_idx]] = new_counts[count[count_idx]] + counts[count]

print(new_counts)
plot_histogram(new_counts)
```

Comment: Now if I want to split that into two qubits  how can I assign  I measure that quantum register and have state ex:$\left|01\right> $ as $\left|0\right> ,\left|1\right> $

Comment: @User1086 may be you are talking about statevector.